# Ruby: undefined method 'to_set' for array?

Tags: ruby

I have a large array of chars:

```
input = ["p", "f", "p", "t" ... "g"]
```

I am attempting to take a slice of the array and convert it into a set:

```
sub = input.slice(0, 4).to_set
```

But the interpreter bombs:

```
undefined method `to_set' for ["p", "f", "p", "t"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Why is this happening? In `irb` this code executes with no issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Enumerable#to_set` method is implemented by Ruby's [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). It is not `require`-d by default hence why you get the error if you try to use it.

But in `irb` `Set` is already required. You can verify that by:

```
require 'set' # => false
```

This is something that [has been raised up as an issue in irb](https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/143) before.

Comment: Ruby 3.2.0 Release Candidate 1 : "Set is now available as a builtin class without the need for require "set". [Feature #16989] It is currently autoloaded via the Set constant or a call to Enumerable#to_set." . So just wait until Christmas...